# Efficient (low latency) ways to communicate between processes?

Tags: android, service, ipc

I'm interested in creating a module that provides new data at around 30hz and want to feed it to applications with the lowest possible **latency** (because of UI issues applications needs to respond and update at around 15-30Hz).

I'm considering either a system service or a kernel module for Android and I'm curious about the different approaches to communicating between my new module and other data-consuming processes.

I'm free to make changes to the Android framework or work at a native layer if necessary.

Just looking through the Binder API, it looks quite heavyweight and slow. Am I right, and what are some alternatives (e.g. pipe files?)

Does a Binder IPC call involve a context switch?

Its seems to me that a shared memory segment would provide the lowest possible latency. Does Android have support for this at the Java level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use NDK, you can use a shared mmaped file object, linux revolves around this